# Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked framework was built for iOS. Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, carthage, xcode12

Getting this error when adding dependency through Carthage.

Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked framework was built for iOS.

Do you have any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Is the framework available as source or only as a compiled binary?

Comment: It is available as source.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for Xcode 12.3

Try to set **Validate Workspace** to **Yes** at **Build Settings** tab

[image: build settings]